# Is it possible to create a grouped stacked bar chart with the .Net chart controls

Tags: .net, graph, charts

Good morning,

I would like to create a grouped stacked bar chart that looks like this:
http://rookery9.aviary.com.s3.amazonaws.com/4419000/4419489_3ed2_625x625.jpg

Jan represents Jan 2009 vs 2010 and Feb represents Feb 2009 vs 2010

Either .net chart controls (preferred) or any other tool is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case of the MS Chart control, if using the Stacked bar / Stacked column types, you can group different series into separate groups by setting the StackedGroupName custom attribute

```
// Set the first two series to be grouped into Group1
Chart1.Series["LightBlue"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";
Chart1.Series["Gold"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";
```

If you download the MS Chart samples (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418), you can see something very similar to what you are looking for in 
/WebSamples/ChartTypes/BarColumnCharts/Stacked/StackedChart.aspx - Grouping option.

Hope this helps!